# How to use setStream in Android Wallpaper Manager

Tags: android

I am trying to set the wallpaper using `setStream` function - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager#setStream(java.io.InputStream)

```
val wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this)
val retval = wallpaperManager.setStream(file.inputStream(), null, false, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK)
```

but the wallpaper is not changing, but I got the `retval` a valid integer number like `612`

i didnt get any error also

what would be the issue, how to solve, thanks